# I want to take input for EMR from Redshift directly (i.e. without using S3). Is it possible ? If yes, then how?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift, amazon-emr

Currently I am putting data in Redshift from S3. Then after done with Redshift, I am putting the data back on S3. Now, from S3 I am taking the data as input to EMR in AWS. 
So the process is like  : S3 -> Redshift -> S3 -> EMR
And what I want is like : S3 -> Redshift -> EMR (Directly from Redshift to EMR). 
So my question is, how to take input for EMR from Redshift ? 
Please provide solutions and links to read deeper.

Comment: Sqoop can pull most relational database into Hadoop. EMR is just Hadoop. Redshift is basically Postgres. Good luck

Comment: Can you explain more on this ?

Comment: I trust in your abilities to search the keywords I just said. Start here. https://sqoop.apache.org/

Comment: Please provide one detailed step by step approach to do this.

Comment: Sorry, can't do. Stackoverflow isn't for tutorials or guides. `sqoop-import` is a really useful tool. I gave you the link to read about it

Comment: This pattern of going via S3 is a recognised best practice - break the pattern at your own peril and be prepared for it to break

Comment: do you want cricket write the code for you too ?

Comment: No I wasn't able to find any good material or blog on this. So all I was asking if he has any good link to provide.